# Is it a good practice to use logging inside classes/functions in Python?

Tags: python

So far, I've been using logging only in `main()` mostly. I do not log anything in my functions or classes but sometimes I feel like it would be helpful.

**What I would do now:**

```
def init_logger():

    # set up logging to file
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    logger = logging.getLogger('testlog')
    h = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()
    h.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    logger.addHandler(h)
    return logger

def x():
    return 5+5

def main():
    logger = init_logger()
    logger.info('starting function x')
    x()
    logger.info('x returned successfully')
```

**But sometimes I want/need to do something like:**

```
def x():
    logger.info('starting x')
    ...
    logger.info('running x')
    ...
    logger.info('finished x')
    return value
```

But this means that I would need to set up logging at the module level, right? E.g.

```
#!/bin/python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And now I can use logging anywhere in my script.

Also, doing so raises other points of consideration such as making sure logging is set up properly if somebody imports my module etc.

So basically, my main question is:

Is it Pythonic to use logging inside classes/methods/functions or should it be used in outer functions such as `main()` - as I do now?

And my subquestion would be:

Should logging be initialized at the module level or inside a function as I've done in my example in `init_logger()`?

Comment: Anyone who imports your module can set up their own logging preferences *after* the import runs, so you don't need to worry about affecting client modules.

Comment: Asking if something is "good practice" or even "Pythonic" is pretty meaningless. Asking if something is a good idea for reaching a **specific** goal makes way more sense. For example, in this case, you should ask if usage of logging can affect or restrict reusability of a module - and the question title and wording should put that goal into focus. Otherwise, this question is prone to get close votes for not being focussed enough.

Comment: Did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 8):

Since the [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is the unit of Python software, a good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level logger, in each module which uses logging, add

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

on top of each module right after `import` statements. This is a singleton so we don't pass it around functions. And of course you can use `logger.info` or debug/error/warn inside any function/class then.

Configuring logging has several possible ways,
Programmers can configure logging in three ways:

> Creating loggers, handlers, and formatters explicitly using Python
> code that calls the configuration methods listed above.
>
> Creating a logging config file and reading it using the fileConfig()
> function.
>
> Creating a dictionary of configuration information and passing it to
> the dictConfig() function.

Refer to [Configuring Logging section in Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not a bad practice to log in a function or a class method.

> Is it Pythonic to use logging inside classes/methods/functions or should it be used in outer functions such as main() - as I do now?

I don't know whether is it Pythonic or not but I guess it is ok ;). Anyway it doesn't make your code more unreadable.

> Should logging be initialized at the module level or inside a function as I've done in my example in init_logger()?

I suggest to init logger *at the module level* as it is basically like importing and other such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do bear in mind that `logging.getLogger(name_of_logger)` will return the exact same logger object as long as name_of_logger is the same.

So you can let the invoking module sets up the logging as they like, and just use a fetched logger object in your functions/classes.

To adopt your example code:

```py
def x():
    logger = logging.getLogger("xlog")
    logger.info('starting x')
    ...
    logger.info('running x')
    ...
    logger.info('finished x')
    return value
```

This frees up the need to initialize the logging in your code. If the user code does not need logging, then user code can just invoke your code. If the user code actually needs logging, then it's the responsibility of the user code to setup all the handlers and formatters for the `"xlog"` logger object.

You can put the information about the `"xlog"` logger in the documentation to your code, like in the docstring of the `x()` function.